# how to render with ReactDOM.render() using ES6?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6

creating class component with ES5 would be like this

```
var someClass = React.createClass({});
```

and rendering it using

```
ReactDOM.render(<someClass/>, elementSelector);
```

creating class component with ES6 somehow be like this

```
class someAnotherClass extends React.Component{
     constructor(){
          super();
     }
     render(){}
}
```

how do we render with ES6?

Comment: Exactly the same way. Note that components must be captialized. See the documentation: https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/rendering-elements.html, https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/components-and-props.html

Answer (score 2):

**Step 1: create Component-**

```
///dashboard.js
import React from 'react';
class Dashboard extends React.Component {    
   render() {
      return (
         <div>
            Dash board
         </div>
      );
   }
}

export default Dashboard;
```

**Step 2: mount it to DOM as-**

```
//index.js
import {render} from 'react-dom';
import Dashboard from './dashboard';

render(<Dashboard/>, document.getElementById('target');
```

Comment: So you are saying... in exactly the same way? Or what are you trying to say with that answer?